# Шифрование строки

Tags: php, rsa

Есть модуль, есть экспонента, есть строка, которую нужно зашифровать:

```
$modulus = 'CD0....C9246E1';
$exponent = '0...1';
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($modulus), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256);
$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
echo $rsa->encrypt('THISISMYSTR');
```

`THISISMYST` - строка, которую пытаюсь зашифровать. Но получаю какую-то гадость на выходе.

Comment: Что такое _какая-то гадость_ в данном случае?

Comment: Не то, что нужно.
Скрипт не шифрует, почему-то, мою строку THISISMYSTR

Comment: То есть `echo` выдаёт строку в первозданном виде?

Comment: Нет, смотрите echo каждый раз выдает совершенно новую строку. 
Ситуация у меня такая.
Сервер выдал мне $modulus и $exponent


У меня есть строка, которую я должен зашифровать по этим данным и послать серверу.

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта гадость на выходе результат работы функции и она в бинарном виде. Для перевода в читаемый вид можно использовать `base64_encode();`

Что касается того, что echo выводит разные строки, если не ошибаюсь, результат работы RSA всегда разный.

Для проверки выполните расшифровку через `$rsa->decrypt()`, если результат будет соответствовать тому, что вы зашифровали, то ваш алгоритм работает правильно.

Comment: Результат работы RSA на одном и том же наборе данных всегда один и тот же, все-таки умножение и вычитание всегда однозначны. Если после каждого запуска программы результат меняется, значит либо ключи изменились, либо реализация шифрования оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: Почему всегда один и тот же? Запустил функцию шифрования в цикле 10 раз, получил 10 разных результатов.

Comment: Действительно, результат шифрования отличается от раза к разу: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325461/1026

Comment: [Чертова реальность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC_.D1.88.D0.B8.D1.84.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B0) (c) )) У меня в голове отложилась только стандартная схема, когда результаты не меняются, но эта схема ненадежна именно из-за того, что результаты одни и те же. Надо будет освежить память.